# structure in getMetadata activity for csv file dataset ignores an extra comma in the files first row

Tags: csv, schema, azure-data-factory

I am using a reference CSV file with just the correct number and name of columns and want to compare its structure with that of incoming CSV files before proceeding to use Copy Data to import the incoming CSV data into Azure SQL. Files arriving in blob storage trigger this pipeline.

The need to validate the structure has arisen due to random files arriving with a trailing comma in the header row which causes a failure in the copy data pipeline as it sees the trailing comma as an extra column.

I have set up a getMetadata for both the reference file & the incoming files. Using an If Condition, I compare schemas.

The problem I have is that the output of getMetadata is ignoring the trailing comma.
I have tried 'column count' & 'structure' arguments. The same problem either way as the getMetadata fails to see the trailing comma as an issue.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with extra commas in header of csv file. Its not ignoring them
> reading those extra commas also as columns.

Please check below screenshots.
[image: File with extra commas]

[image]